# Undefined function or variable 'stdout'

Tags: matlab

I am trying to compile a code for MATLAB. Actually is in C and there is an [implementation in matlab](https://github.com/wg-perception/PartsBasedDetector). Thus I am using `MinGW64 Compiler (C)` compiler in order to compile the files. I am running the compiler script which actually compiles using the cmd all the c files. My problem is with a line with `fflush(stdout);` When I tried to run that command I am receiving the following message:

> ```
> Undefined function or variable 'stdout'.
> ```

I am trying to figure out why am I receiving that error, and what is about. 
The code is the following:

```
disp('Compiling for Matlab...');
gcc = 'mex';
cd mex;

% =============
% Learning code
disp('Learning:');
files = {'qp_one_sparse.cc', 'score.cc', 'lincomb.cc'};
matlabflags = '-O -largeArrayDims';

for n = 1:length(files)
  cmd = [gcc ' ' matlabflags ' ' files{n}];
  disp(['  ' cmd]); 
  fflush(stdout);
  eval(cmd); 
end
```

I got issues with `fflush(stdout);` line

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you included `stdio.h`?

Comment: I don't see `c` code here..

Comment: Yes but my problem lies with the stdout variable.

Comment: It is not `c`, so remove the tag.

Comment: MATLAB does not have `fflush` or `stdout`.

Comment: @excaza: No, it's octave code.

Answer (score 1):

`fflush(stdout)` is valid in Octave but *not* MATLAB.

If you need to flush the output, you can [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) to achieve the same effect in MATLAB.

```
drawnow('update')
```

The `update` parameter ensures that only non-graphical queues are flushed.

In newer versions of MATLAB, the following is preferred but either should work.

```
drawnow('limitrate')
```

That being said, I'm not sure that you even need it for the code that you've posted.